# ACS - Census Block Groups with 0 households?

Tags: usa, us-census, census

I'm looking through some ACS data on # of households by block group in Santa Clara County. Block Group 2, Census Tract 5002, Santa Clara County, California has 0 households, despite having a population estimate of 737. This is true for the five-year estimates from 2013, 2014, 2015, and 2016.

I thought Census block groups had a population requirement (except for bodies of water, which would be block group 0)?

Any advice or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: What is ACS data? You're talking to a world wide audience here (so your question needs a US tag too).

Comment: This helps you in no way whatsoever, but I'm guessing you're talking about ACS_2014_5YR_BG.gdb.zip (but you should point to a URL source), and I ran into a similar issue when writing https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/QUORA/bc-us-split.pl -- there are quite a few blockgroups with 0 people. I realize your case is slightly different (blockgroups with people but no households), but thought I'd mention this.

Answer (score 2):

Block groups are generally divided by roads and administrative boundaries. Based on the reality of their delineation, they are not divided by population explicitly.

What you have here is a block group that includes the Santa Clara County Jail and the Santa Clara Juvenile Hall. They are considered a part of the [group quarters](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/about/glossary/housing.html) population.

The household living situation of your [block group](https://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/16_5YR/B09019/1500000US060855002002).

A [google maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Santa+Clara+Juvenile+Hall/@37.3498942,-121.9101092,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x808fcb794fc73357:0xb29bb1fcdaf171d9!8m2!3d37.34989!4d-121.9079205) for the area.

You can also contact the [ACS Data Users Group](https://acsdatacommunity.prb.org/).